# Mongodb find query does not work when the condition variable value is passed through loop in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, mongodb-query

```
for (var j = 0; j < u1.similar_users.length; j++) {
    var pp = u1.similar_users[j];
    console.log(pp);
    db.collection('userdata').find({ user: pp }, { restaurants: true, _id: false }), (function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);

        for (var tt = 0; tt < res.length; tt++) {

            console.log(res[tt]);
            var u1 = res[tt];
            //console.log(u1.similar_users.length);
            console.log(u1.restaurants);
        }
    });
}
```

Userdata collection is as follows:

```
{
    "user": "falak",
    "restaurants": [
    {
        "name": "subway",
        "address": "1, Kondeshwar Bhuvan, Tilak Road, Ghatkopar East, Mumbai",
        "locality": "Ghatkopar East",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "cuisines": "North Indian, South Indian, Chinese"
    }],
    "similar_users": [
        " ashu"
    ]
}
```

Here,i trying to find and display the resturant of the users ,and the value of the user is passed dynamically .But it is unable to access the 'pp' variable inside the find query. Whereas it works well and gets displayed in the console.Also if the value for user var is passed manually such as "user: 'abc' "
it works,but it is not working inside loop.As a result ,the res var after the find query also returns 0 as the length,as no data is fetched using find().Please help

Comment: The `console.log(res);` is working?? If so what is the output?

Comment: You shouldn't make multiple db queries inside for loop. You should let the db do the heavy lifting for you by making a single query which would return exactly what you need. `db.collection('userdata').find({ user: { $in: u1.similar_users } },....` $in operator docs here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla It works manually ,as user:abc but i want the name of user dynamically which  is accessed from array and passed as variable in loop ,this doesnt work.Please help

Comment: @Molda I tried ,still its not working and result is null

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I  tried the same thing as you said ,by creating array still it it returning null result .

Comment: Update your post and add the new code.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution the problem must that you are not calling a callback properly, try this:

```
for(var j=0;j<u1.similar_users.length;j++)
{
    var pp=u1.similar_users[j];
    console.log(pp);                   // Make sure you have the correct values
    db.collection('userdata')
        .find( {user:pp}, {restaurants:1,_id:0} )
        .toArray((error, docs) => {                // chaining toArray method!!
            if (error) return process.exit(1);
            console.log(docs);
            // other stuff
        });

}
```

But as [@Molda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284355/molda) is pointing out, you should delegate in the DB to perform all the searching, something like this:

```
var ppArray = [];         // An array to store all the values you want to search

for(var j=0;j<u1.similar_users.length;j++)
    pp.push(u1.similar_users[j]);               // Populate the array

console.log(ppArray);

db.collection('userdata')
    .find( { user: { $in : ppArray} }, {restaurants:1,_id:0} )  // Search all the documents
    .toArray((error, docs) => {
        if (error) return process.exit(1);
        console.log(docs);
        // other stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your code more closely and noticed in this code

`...._id: false }), (function(err...`

those parentheses `), (` are not supposed to be there.

This code `db.collection(..).find()` has esentially no connection to the next function `(function(...){....})`

Your code written to show the mistake you made:

```
db.collection('userdata').find({ user: pp }, { restaurants: true, _id: false }); 

// i replaced , with ; since it has same effect here

// this is immediately invoked function expression 
// which has nothing to do with the code above
// both err and res are undefined no matter what the above query returns
(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);

    for (var tt = 0; tt < res.length; tt++) {

        console.log(res[tt]);
        var u1 = res[tt];
        //console.log(u1.similar_users.length);
        console.log(u1.restaurants);
    }
});
```

This should work as expected

```
db.collection('userdata').find({ user: { $in: u1.similar_users }, { restaurants: true, _id: false }, function(err, res) {

    console.log(res);

});
```